# PHP date function for formatting time

Tags: php

I am using the date function to get formatted time for timestamps between 0 and 86400. Therefore I expect to get 12:00am for timestamp 0, but instead I get 1:00am. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your timezone setting, use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/gmdate) instead

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the timezone your PHP date() function uses. It's probably +1:00 now.